# hibernate createCriteria on a FK field is not working for me

Tags: hibernate, foreign-key-relationship, postgresql-9.1, query-by-example

I've been stuck with this for a while and cannot make progress. The question is how to use Hibernate's *createCriteria* when the restrictive field in DB is a FK.

Here are 2 tables: *account* and *cf_account_type*, which represents the qualifier (client, employee, etc)

```
    CREATE TABLE account (
        usern character varying(30) NOT NULL,
        cf_account_type character varying(30) NOT NULL
    );
    ALTER TABLE ONLY account
        ADD CONSTRAINT pk_account366 PRIMARY KEY (usern);

    CREATE TABLE cf_account_type (
        cf_account_type character varying(30) NOT NULL
    );
    ALTER TABLE ONLY cf_account_type
        ADD CONSTRAINT pk_cf_account_type373 PRIMARY KEY (cf_account_type);

    ALTER TABLE ONLY account
        ADD CONSTRAINT fk_account465 FOREIGN KEY (cf_account_type) 
        REFERENCES cf_account_type(cf_account_type);
```

The solution Hibernate documentation suggests is found
[here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) and looks like this:

```
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.setSex('F');
    cat.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
        .add( Example.create(cat) )
        .list();
```

However, *sex* and *color* are not objects but plain text fields. So, the problem is that my code **returs all rows from *account* and doesn't seem to take into account the restriction**.

```
    Session session = SF.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    //creating an example instance
    Account instance = new Account();
    instance.setCfAccountType(cfAccountType);

    //fetching from db
    List<Account> result = (List<Account>)session.
            createCriteria(Account.class).
                    add(Example.create(instance)).list();
    tx.commit();
```

Additional information:

The DB is PostgreSQL 9.1.2 and it is being connected via JDBC4 (postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar)

Outtake from hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">CENSORED</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CENSORED</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples):

> Version properties, identifiers **and associations** are ignored. By
>   default, null valued properties are excluded.

(emphasis mine)

You'll need to use a regular criteria restriction:

```
session.createCriteria(Account.class, "account")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("account.cfAccountType", cfAccountType)
       .list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting usage of QBE from [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples):

> Version properties, identifiers and **associations are ignored**. By
>   default, null valued properties are excluded.

Although, it then shows an example of placing criteria upon associated objects:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .createCriteria("mate")
        .add( Example.create( cat.getMate() ) )
    .list();
```

Apply it to your case:

```
List<Account> result = (List<Account>) session.createCriteria(Account.class)
                .add(Example.create(instance))
                .createCriteria("ofAccountType")
                     .add(Example.create(instance.getOfAccountType()))
                     .list();
```